# Disable viewing or require password to access Google Chrome History

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Often, because of various reasons (mostly to show other people a webpage to view or edit on which requires some sort of setup or login), I need to give people physical access to my fully unlocked laptop. That means they can see my browsing history, and I don't want that to happen due to privacy reasons. I already have a script that allows me to stop the Dock process (thereby eliminating the ability to navigate to other applications except the current one), so other application is not a concern. How can I temporarily disable access to view history or protect it with password without having to restart Google Chrome?

Comment: Something like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to keep your browser history (and everything else) to yourself is to either enable the Guest account or setup a "throwaway" account on your Mac and then use Fast User Switching to change accounts whenever somebody wants to use a browser quickly.

Comment: The main reason to share my computer is because there are something on the page that the other person needs to view and/or edit. Mostly that's OneNote, but sometimes also other things. What you suggest defeats the purpose because opening the webpage in another user account has the same level of difficulty as opening it on the other person's laptop.

Comment: @JoyJin Is this the same computer you are using as root?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure how does that relate to this problem.

Comment: @JoyJin Preventing users from accessing browser history/other tabs seems to be the lesser issue than preventing them from wrecking your whole system :-)

Comment: Yes. I see your point. But I trust that the other person does not know enough about macOS / command-line utilities to cause significant amounts of damage. In the worst case, I have hourly snapshots. Thank you for your advice though, I didn't think of that. Thank you for your suggestion for the extension. However, it requires restarting Google Chrome, which is something I want to avoid because I have many working tabs open (like Desmos for scratch work).