# Lock Google Chrome to current tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Often, because of educational reasons, I need to give people physical access to my fully unlocked laptop. That means they can temper with Google Chrome, and someone had actually closed several of my tabs without my permission before. I already have a script that allows me to stop the Dock process (thereby eliminating the ability to navigate to other applications except the current one), so other application is not a concern.

How can I lock Google Chrome to a single tab (that is, the person cannot interact with the browser (switch tabs, open/close/edit existing tabs/windows, access menu options), only view and interact with the current page) without having to restart Google Chrome?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410670/9058 :-)

Comment: No, it's fine. I would probably look for Chrome Extentions for this.